# semantic-ui dropdown not working in Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, semantic-ui

I have this dropdown box in my HTML template

```
    <div class="ui dropdown selection">
       <input type="hidden" ngModel name="gender">
       <div class="default text">Select Gender</div>
         <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
             <div class="item" data-value="male">Male</div>
             <div class="item" data-value="female">Female</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

And the script inside `component.ts` form

```
export class HomeComponent{
  constructor(){
    jQuery('ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  }
}
```

The drop down box is visible on the UI  but it is not listing the options and showing the selection.

Comment: Have you imported the jquery library into your angular.cli.json? and then have you declared it at the top of your component.ts?

Comment: @A61NN5 Yes I did.

Comment: I thin this should solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013313/bootstrap-dropdown-with-angular-6/51058448