# Dropdown in angular6 for a menu not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

I am trying to open a menu on click of side bar item. However the click does nothing. I am not sure how can i fix this in angular6.

```
<li *ngIf="mUser.role.accountant !== true" class="nav-item dropdown" routerLinkActive="open">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span class="icon-holder">
      <i class="ti-server"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="title">Food/Drink</span>
    <span class="arrow">
      <i class="ti-angle-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="" [routerLink]="['/drink']">Drinks</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" [routerLink]="['/food']">Food</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: please see this answer
[51013313](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013313/bootstrap-dropdown-with-angular-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `ngbDropdownToggle`, `ngbDropdownMenu` attributes and classes:

```
<li *ngIf="mUser.role.accountant !== true" class="nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown>
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ngbDropdownToggle>
    <span class="icon-holder">
      <i class="ti-server"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="title">Food/Drink</span>
    <span class="arrow">
      <i class="ti-angle-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/drink']">Drinks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/food']">Food</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This seems to be working but CSS is weird, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `href`

Try like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/drink']">Drinks</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to import bootstrap js

Also This is answer help you for your question.

> [Bootstrap dropdown with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013313/bootstrap-dropdown-with-angular-6)