# Bootstrap 4 dropdown with fixed position outside navbar-collapse (Mobile/small screen)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put a div in the navbar in such a way that its position is fixed in all the size of screens. It should come out toggle button and always visible to user. For eg like notification icon on navbar, if i see same navbar in my mobile notification icon should be visible instead of collasiping under navbar-collapse.

below is my html code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-template">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row order-2 order-lg-3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-3 order-lg-2" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image: this is output which i am expecting]

But as soon as i open dropdown its expanding the navbar like this [image: dropdown link open in navbar]

How to control this expanding with navbar-collapse and fixed dropdown on navbar

Answer (score 0):

Did you have some javascript dependecies like jquery and popper.js

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The same issue was also with Angular: [Bootstrap dropdown with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013313/bootstrap-dropdown-with-angular-6/51058448)

Comment: i have those dependency. But here problem is with dropdown behaviour if you fix a dropdown outside navbar-collapse. if you open the dropdown it will expand the navbar

Comment: i suggest you to visit https://www.codeply.com/go/TWZGiy3VGw and paste my code mention in the question you will see the problem. check in mobile view

Comment: Try adding an div and put all of them
<div class="container">
// your code
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because navbar nav class in bootstrap by default is set to
position: static;

To override it, create an id in your dropdown menu div tag, e.g.,

```css
#absolute {
    position:absolute
}
```

and

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="absolute" >
```

If this doesn't work, inspect your webpage using your browser and try unchecking position in navbar class so you know where exactly your problem is.

```css
#absolute {
    position:absolute
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-template">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row order-2 order-lg-3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="absolute">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-3 order-lg-2" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
Return to post
```

Answer (score 0):

I would better fix this for all dropdowns inside navbars.

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-template">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row order-2 order-lg-3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-3 order-lg-2" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```