# Bootstrap close on click except for links

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

My issue is similar to another SO question below, but I want to change the nesting
[Bootstrap dropdown with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013313/bootstrap-dropdown-with-angular-6)

I need the menu to close when someone clicks anywhere in the dropdown, except for the nested links. If the nested links are clicked, I want it to follow the link. Bonus points to have it follow the link *and* close the dropdown.

I can either get it to close anywhere on click, or it stays open but follows the links.

I'm using ng-bootstrap 12.0.0. To the best of my knowledge, this is AngularJS.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Content here -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notification Text1 <a href="some-link">Nested Link1</a></div>
                <div class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notification Text1 <a href="some-link">Nested Link1</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div
```

Comment: you're not using ng-bootstrap else only bootstrap. ng-bootstrap is an angular library that use bootstrap.css but is **not** bootstrap. Bootstrap is a javascript library with a few components

Comment: I did it [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src/navbar-item/navbar-item.component.ts#L88)

Answer (score 1):

In ng-bootstrap there're a "property" "autoclose", you can give as value "outside" and close manually the menu in all the anothers buttons. Some like

```
<div
  class="d-inline-block"
  ngbDropdown
  #menu="ngbDropdown"
  [autoClose]="'outside'"
>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2"
    id="dropdownManual"
    ngbDropdownAnchor
    (focus)="menu.open()"
  >
    Toggle dropdown
  </button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownManual">
    <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="menu.close()">Action - 1</button>
    <div ngbDropdown #submenu="ngbDropdown" placement="right-top">
      <button ngbDropdownItem ngbDropdownAnchor (click)="submenu.toggle()">
        Another Action
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownManual">
        <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="menu.close()">Action - 1 - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="menu.close()">Action - 1 - 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="menu.close()">
      Something else is here
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avw69o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-manual.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-manual.ts)

when we use bootstrap with Angular we need add the bootstrap and @types/bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap@5.2.3
npm install @types/bootstrap@5.2.3
```

Then we can import dropdown from bootstrap

```
import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap';
```

We can to have a .html like this (see the template reference variables "#menu") and **IMPORTANT** not forget the attribute `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` in ours menus.

in the main menu we added `data-bs-auto-close="outside"` so only is closed when we click outside

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Content here -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
            <a #menu class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" 
            data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="dropdown-item" >Nested Link1</div>
                <div class="dropdown-item" >Nested Link1</div>
                <div class="dropdown-item drowpdown dropend">
                  <div #menu class="dropdown-toggle w-100" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" >Nested Link1</div>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-item" >Nested Link1</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item" >Nested Link1</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Now, we get the "menus" using viewChild and in ngAtferViewInit, we are going to store the dropdowns

```
  menus: Dropdown[]; //<--here store ours menus

  @ViewChildren('menu') elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.menus = this.elements
      .toArray()
      .map((x) => new Dropdown(x.nativeElement));
  }
```

Finally we write a function close

```
  close(target: any) {
    if (!target.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle') )
      this.menus.forEach((x) => x.hide());
  }
```

And add as .css some like

```
.dropdown-item.drowpdown.dropend
{
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
}
.dropdown-item.drowpdown.dropend >div
{
  padding-left:1rem;
  padding-right:1rem;

}
```

To get that the div with the submenu have full width

Now simply add to theh `<li class="nav-item dropdown"` a call to the function

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown" (mouseup)="close($event.target)">
   ...
 </li>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fob4q5?file=src%2Fmain.ts)